# C using a pointer to a string in a function

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

a quick question. I'm trying to write a function which recieves a name of a string and prints its second character, But it won't compile (on http://ideone.com), can you address the issue? I don't see the problem as I am sending an address into the function, and asking to access the character in that address.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[4] = "abc";
    test(line);
    return 0;
}

void test(int point) {
    point++;
    printf("%c",*point);
    return;
}
```

The compile error that I am getting is -

```
Compilation error   time: 0 memory: 10320 signal:0
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:5:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘test’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  test(line);
  ^~~~
prog.c: At top level:
prog.c:9:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘test’
 void test(int point) {
      ^~~~
prog.c:5:2: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘test’ was here
  test(line);
  ^~~~
prog.c: In function ‘test’:
prog.c:11:14: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
  printf("%c",*point);
              ^~~~~~
```

Comment: Why do you use `int` instead of `char*` ? Also `int` can not be dereferenced.

Comment: Should be `test(char* point)`

Comment: If you actually read the words in the error message, they're quite specific. You **do** have to actually read them, though. They're not just there to take up space on the screen; they actually convey information.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/qmO40m) on ideone.

Answer (score 4):

Two problems here.

First, you use the function `test` before it's declared.  So the function is implicitly declared as taking an unspecified number of arguments and returning `int`, i.e. `int test()`.  This conflict with the definition `void test(int point)` that appears later.

The second issue is that you pass a `char` array (which decays to a `char *`) to `test`, but the function is expecting an `int`.

Move the definition of `test` to before `main` so that is defined before it's used, and change the `point` parameter from `int` to `char *`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(char *point) {
    point++;
    printf("%c",*point);
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    char line[4] = "abc";
    test(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) It wants a function prototype or for the function to be declared above your main.

2) The parameter *point* in

```
void test (int point)
```

is a pointer, not an int.